# Check for value before inserting

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to check for a value before inserting into the table my code currently looks like this:

```
try {
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
     $stmt->bindValue(':firstname', $first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(':lastname', $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();
        echo 'New record created successfully';
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $smtp . "<br/> " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: You check by testing. Which variable did you want to test?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *check for a value*?

Comment: Perform a SELECT query and check num_rows to verify.

Comment: I want to test firstname to make sure it doesn't exist in the database before inserting

Comment: Btw, there could be *n* users with same first and last name. All you need to worry about is the email address here.

Comment: And the simplest way out, is to make it UNIQUE in database structure.

Comment: That's a very good point I didn't' think of that actually